# Please help me with my python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a discord bot in python that searches if a member has some specific words/characters in their name (like "hello" or "ЯΛY") and if they do, they will get kicked. I have already attempted to first completely print out all user names in the server, but from then on I couldn't progress further as I didn't know how to add these names to a variable/list where from then on I could just scan it. If anyone is interested in my code that I made already:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix='?')

@client.command()
async def members(ctx):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)


client.run("funny token")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna want their username so grab that from `member.name`
Then check if there is a substring in their name and if it includes your blacklisted text then call the kick method on member. check out the [API refrence.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.kick)
so:

```py
if "someText" in member.name:
    member.kick(reason)
```

Comment: Thanks, now my bot can find all the persons with these special characters in their name. I can't get the bot to kick them though, and I cant figure out why. The script runs without any errors but after it finishes, nothing happened (and the persons are still in my server). Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: try doing `await member.kick(reason="False username")`